# Extract only the error message in custom exception message

Tags: visualforce, exception, apexpage

**Class:** (Custom Exception)

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

}
```

Using as below in my help class:

```
throw new CustomErrorException('No other characters allowed');
```

This is working perfectly both from API and UI. But when an exception occurs, it is showing the error message *including class name, error line* (as shown in below screenshot). However, I would like to display only the error message and omit the other part. As this is custom exception, I cannot use `ApexPages.Severity.FATAL`.

Are there any ways to achieve this. Thanks

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to use a `catch` block in tandem with `ApexPages.addMessages` if you want that sort of clean interface. The fact that it's a custom exception by no means indicates you can't use this approach.

**Demo**

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    public class CustomException extends Exception { }
    public MyController()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new CustomException('All your base are belong to us');
        }
        catch (CustomException error)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(error);
        }
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

You can replace the `throw` statement above with any operation that could result in your custom `Exception` type, including `DML Operations` inducing that behavior.